# Multiple type parameters in type class

Tags: scala, typeclass

I want to use type class to design convert interface and codes are as below:

```
case class Kilograms(value: Double)

case class Pounds(value: Double)

trait Convert[T, U] {
  def convert(input: T): U
}

object Convert {
  def apply[T:Convert, U:Convert] = implicitly[Convert[T,U]]
  def covert[T, U](input: T)(implicit c: Convert[T, U]): U = c.convert(input)

  implicit object kilogramsToPounds extends Convert[Kilograms, Pounds] {
      override def convert(input: Kilograms): Pounds = Pounds(input.value *   2.20462)
    }

  implicit object poundsToKilograms extends Convert[Pounds, Kilograms] {
      override def convert(input: Pounds): Kilograms = Kilograms(input.value / 2.20462)
    }
}
```

But compile error:

```
Error: wrong number of type arguments for A$A95.this.Convert, should be 2
 def apply[T:Convert, U:Convert] = implicitly[Convert[T,U]]

 Error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: A$A95.this.Convert[T,U]
  def apply[T:Convert, U:Convert] = implicitly[Convert[T,U]]

Error: not enough arguments for method implicitly: (implicit e:   A$A95.this.Convert[T,U])A$A95.this.Convert[T,U].
Unspecified value parameter e.
   def apply[T:Convert, U:Convert] = implicitly[Convert[T,U]]
```

If I change `def apply[T:Convert, U:Convert] = implicitly[Convert[T,U]]` into `def apply[T, U](implicit c: Convert[T, U]): Convert[T, U] = c`, no compile error!!!

I would like to know what's going on?
Also, I look up some information, context bound is restricted with single type parameter(?)
If I want to implement multiple type parameter type class, how should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The context-bound syntax `T : U` only works for types `U` that have only *one type parameter* `S` (which conforms to `T`).

This is valid because you are manually declaring the implicit for `Convert[T, U]`:

```
def covert[T, U](input: T)(implicit c: Convert[T, U]): U = c.convert(input)
```

The following is not valid, because the compiler de-sugars the context bounds to `Convert[T]` and `Convert[U]` respectively, which doesn't make sense.

```
 def apply[T:Convert, U:Convert] = implicitly[Convert[T,U]]
```

(attempts to de-sugar to)

```
 def apply[T, U](implicit ev1: Convert[T], ev2: Convert[U]) = ...
```

See the [SLS 7.4 - Context and View Bounds](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicits.html#context-bounds-and-view-bounds):

> A type parameter `A` of a method or non-trait class may also have one or more context bounds `A : T`. In this case the type parameter may be instantiated to any type `S` for which evidence exists at the instantiation point that `S` satisfies the bound `T`. Such evidence consists of an implicit value with type `T[S]`.